# LINQ error- cannot covert IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, linq

This is the code:

```
IEnumerable<StockVendorHistoryModal> vendorhistoryList
    = Session.Query<PurchaseOrderLineItem>()
             .Where(popredicate)
             .Where(p => p.Stock.Number != null)
             .Select(c => new StockVendorHistoryModal
                    {
                        StockId = c.Stock.Id,
                        LastPurchaseDate = c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                        VendorNumber = c.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderVendor.Vendor.Number,
                        LastPurchasePrice = c.UnitPrice,
                        LastTransactionDate =
                            c.LastTransactionDate != null ? c.LastTransactionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : null,
                        LeadTimeDays = GetDays(c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate, c.LastTransactionDate),
                    })
             .GroupBy(d => d.VendorNumber).ToList()
             .Select(gpo => gpo.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastPurchaseDate)
             .Take(4);
```

Which is causing this error:

> Cannot convert IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> to IEnumerable<object>

I don't understand. What is the solution?

Comment: Hard to tell...I don't know what `PurchaseOrderLineItem` looks like.

Comment: Looking at the error looks like you have to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

Comment: Use `SelectMany` in your second `Select`

Comment: Yes @PiotrWolkowski and rexcfnghk, SelectMany works. Thanks

Comment: Can you post that as the answer then mark the question as answered? That helps for others coming through who may have a similar question. Also, as an FYI, for debugging linq it can be helpful to split each operation into a separate line, so at least you can figure out which line is causing your problems.

Comment: @qazifarhan Posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are selecting a collection of collections. What you need is to flatten whatever you selecting. You will achieve your goal by replacing the `Select` with `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        IEnumerable<StockVendorHistoryModal> vendorhistoryList = Session.Query<PurchaseOrderLineItem>()
            .Where(popredicate)
            .Where(p => p.Stock.Number != null)
            .Select(c => new StockVendorHistoryModal
            {
                StockId = c.Stock.Id,
                LastPurchaseDate = c.PurchaseOrder == null ? null : c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                VendorNumber =   c.PurchaseOrder == null ? string.Empty : c.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderVendor.Vendor.Number,
                VendorName = c.PurchaseOrder == null ? string.Empty : c.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderVendor.Vendor.Name,
                LastPurchasePrice = c.UnitPrice,
                LastTransactionDate = c.LastTransactionDate != null ? c.LastTransactionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : null,
                LeadTimeDays = GetDays(c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate, c.LastTransactionDate),
            }).GroupBy(d => d.VendorNumber)
            .SelectMany(gpo => gpo.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastPurchaseDate).Take(4));
```

This is working exactly as I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
IEnumerable<StockVendorHistoryModal> vendorhistoryList
= Session.Query<PurchaseOrderLineItem>()
         .Where(popredicate)
         .Where(p => p.Stock.Number != null)
         .Select(c => new StockVendorHistoryModal
                {
                    StockId = c.Stock.Id,
                    LastPurchaseDate = c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                    VendorNumber = c.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderVendor.Vendor.Number,
                    LastPurchasePrice = c.UnitPrice,
                    LastTransactionDate =
                        c.LastTransactionDate != null ? c.LastTransactionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : null,
                    LeadTimeDays = GetDays(c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate, c.LastTransactionDate),
                })
         .GroupBy(d => d.VendorNumber).ToList()
         .Select(gpo => gpo.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastPurchaseDate)
         .Take(4)
         .Select(g => g.First());
```